# I cannot set onLongClick Listener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

Newest Edit ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
I updated code and it is correct now, although I cannot get the functionality to run. On long click event nothing happens...

---

In My file that displays list of rows from database I put the code for setting `OnLongClickListener` but part of the code (commented) returns an error: `The constructor ListView(Monday.MyDiary) is undefined`.

**Here is my file with inserted new code:**

```
package com.example.classorganizer;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;






public class Monday extends ListActivity {



private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;

        ListView listView = new ListView(this); //here the error pops out
        listView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                new EditListItemDialog(v.getContext()).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();


    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

**I also created a Dialog file:**

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((TextView) editText).getText().toString();//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. WHat I was looking to achieve is functionality for editing rows displayed in list by longclicking on them.

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

now the code looks like this:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(Monday.this);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new View.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                new EditListItemDialog(v.getContext()).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Error occurs in View.OnItemLongClickListener in second line

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updated code without errors, but not sure if it's right:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(Monday.this);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
```

You should pass to ListView constructor a context, not a `MyDiary` object.

Fix it using

```
ListView listView = new ListView(Monday.this);
```

It should work since your MyDiary is an innerclass of Monday and is not static.

If you change this, you should pass to MyDiary constructor the `Context` of the activity and use it.

---

And, for your next question: You should use `OnItemLongClickListener` in a ListView, not `OnLongClickListener`.

Comment: Your answer fixed my error. But can you tell me why dialog does not start upon LongClick?

Comment: Have you changed onLongClick with setOnItemLongClickListener?

Comment: now it complains that: View.OnItemLongClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Where you changed it?

Comment: I changed this: listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new View.OnItemLongClickListener() { //second line of code

Comment: Maybe you missed the import? add this in top of the file import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

Comment: still complains View.OnItemLongClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: try to change View. with AdapterView. // AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener

Comment: - AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener) in the type 
  AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemLongClickListener(){})

Comment: Reading comment in the other answer: you should import ListView too import android.widget.ListView;

Comment: Change new OnItemLongClickListener with new View.OnItemLongClickListener

Comment: "Change new OnItemLongClickListener with new View.OnItemLongClickListener" => have you tried it?

Comment: in this case it says that View.OnItemLongClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: have you added all imports?

Comment: I updated my question to give you an insight into how it looks now.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno any idea why this View.OnItemLongClickListener complaints?

Comment: If it says "cannot be resolved to a type" it means you missed an import. Please use the "auto-import" in your IDE

Comment: Change your onLongClick(View v) with onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno ok, new code doesn't bring new errors, but the old one remains.

Comment: now, I changed View.OnItemLongClickListener to AdapterView and error disappeared, although now v in 5th lane complaints that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I changed this v to view and now there are no errors at all, but I am not sure if code is right. I will update it in my question.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno is it enough then to be able to use long click functionality on my list?

Comment: Why not just test it? Anyway yes.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno when I run the code, rows in my list are clickable but nothing happens. I guess that Dialog file does not start

Comment: @MarcoAcierno can you please help me with this OnItemLingClick? I spent whole day on looking for the solution and cannot figure out why dialog does not show up...

Answer (score 1):

`Listview` can not have `setonLongClickListener` you are supposed to implement the `setOnItemItemLongClickListener` as `ListView` contains the list of items so you can always implement the its items long click listener as below:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: when I use your answer eclipse returns few errors. - listView cannot be resolved
 - OnItemLongClickListener cannot be resolved to a type and The method onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type new OnItemLongClickListener(){} must 
 override or implement a supertype method

Comment: @lisoslaw Just import the line `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;` and check. OR press `Ctrl+Shift+O`

Comment: changed it and imported. Now the error listView cannot be resolved pops out in the firt line of your code

Comment: I said just press `Ctrl+Shift+O`.

Comment: I've done it but errors remain. it says listView cannot be resolved //in first line listView complains

Comment: Its just your `ListView` only. Can you post your errors screenshot?

Comment: yes, it's only listView from first line that complaints listView cannot be resolved

Comment: Please update your code. and post screenshot of your error. Make sure you have imported the statement `import android.widget.ListView;`

Comment: I am not sure how to paste screenshot.

Comment: but I imported listView and OnItemLongClickListener as well

Comment: @GrlsHu there are no errors now but I am still unable to run Dialog to update rows from the list...