# Create toast like options menu item tap and hold message

Tags: android, toast

So I searched a lot but didn't get that how to create a toast like message that options menu provide on long tap on them. I'm sure there is a official way to do that, I want to create that message box on button long tap.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "Have a good day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Result I want without using a custom toast sample given below

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah1e8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a button (with the onLongClickListener) as ActionView on the MenuItem, as described in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899386/9863305